# Orthochronous Lorentz is time preserving and $\operatorname{SL}(2,R)$

Tags: group-theory, differential-geometry, lie-groups

Let's consider the pseudosphere in $\mathbb{R}^{1,2}$ given by $x^2+y^2-z^2=-R^2.$
We know that the group $O(1,2)=\{ A \in \operatorname{Mat}(3,\mathbb{R}): A^tGA=G \}$ where $G=\operatorname{diag}(-1,-1,1)$
leaves the pseudosphere invariant. Now we are interested in the following:

i. How can we show that $O_+(1,2)=\{ A: a_{33}>0 \}$ is a subgroup and, more importantly, maps the upper cone to the upper cone?

ii. What is the relation between the groups $O_+(1,2)$ and $\operatorname{SL}(2,\mathbb{R})$ ?

Comment: I think posting the same question on the physics and math page is discouraged.

Comment: maybe. I've been explained the relation (ii) between the connected (to identity) component of $O_+$ and $PSL$ and I'm more or less fine with (i.i) $O_+$ being subgroup, still I'm not sure how to play with the algebra to show it preservs the upper cone